# Yahoo finance API field misalignment

Tags: api, csv, yahoo-finance

I'm trying to use the Yahoo Finance API to create a custom csv but depending upon the stock there is  field misalignment.

For instance, if I just want to download the "k3" field for yahoo which corresponds to last trade size, I would craft the url like so:

http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=yhoo&f=k3

However, if you download that csv there are two columns of data.

Similarly, if I decide to get Float Shares , I want the url:

http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=yhoo&f=f6

However that gives me 3 columns. Is there a way to get it in exactly one column? I want to automate this process but the different column orientations make it very difficult as different rows then have different column lengths and I am unable to easily match up the column name with the row.

Bonus: If someone can explain where the 3 float share numbers come from that would be great, I seem  to only be able to match up the first to the site...

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

In short, you are describing known bugs that Yahoo isn't going to fix as the feed is officially unsupported.

Specifically re. Float (f6): the number returned ***is*** the entire float. It is not 3 csv numbers. The commas are not delimiters; rather, they are 1,000s separators. (I suspect the same is the case with K3. As it is with a couple of other known numbers. (See link below.))

Two solutions:
(1) Write your own workaround using conditional statements (if or case) in your code.
(2) Download the buggy parameters separately from the clean ones.

See: [Yahoo's official reply to your question.](http://developer.yahoo.com/forum/General-Discussion-at-YDN/Stock-Quote-API-returning-commas-in/1234765072000-6036c128-a7e0-3aa5-9e72-1af1871e1b41)

Answer (score 0):

The multiple columns is because that excel (or whatever csv viewer you are using) treats "thousand-seperator" as the the "comma-seperator". We used to have this problem in our school project, and found a hack which is good only if you are using this api for some hobby project and not concerning data usage.

The idea is instead of treating the results as a csv, pick a static column (column A) where you will know the value beforehand (e.g. column 's' stock symbol) or put this value as the first column. When constructing the query, use this column to surround those columns (float columns) with formatting problem. once you get the quotes.csv, manual seperate the results on the column A value.

for example using

http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=yhoo&f=sf6sa5sb6

will get you

"YHOO",   887,675,000,"YHOO",400,"YHOO",N/A

Then use `,"YHOO",` to seperate the results (excluding first column).

Not an elegent way to solve the problem, but at least it gives you the correct result.